# C# refresh websocket live async data in datagridview or listview

Tags: c#, listview, asynchronous, websocket, datagridview

Let me start with saying that I'm a beginning C# programmer with about 6 months of experience. I might not follow best practices but I'm eager to learn. :)

I'm building a small application that shows all the orders and trades I'm making live on my exchange. This exchange provides a WebSocket server to which I can successfully subscribe. Data is coming in and I can successfully queue it and process it synchronously. In my application I have a DataGridView with a binding source linked to it. This DataGridView needs to show all my open orders. When an order is filled it must disappear from the list, when I open a new one, it should show in the list. Very basic.

I'm using an MVP model, for the first time in my life. Updating a label is easy but managing a DataGridView I find a bit more complex. I'm wondering what would be the best way to have a DataGridView that is always up to date.

My Form:

```
public partial class MTMainForm : Form, IMTMainForm
{
  public BindingSource bSRCOrders
  {
    get => (BindingSource)dGVOrders.DataSource;
    set => SetBindingSRC(dGVOrders, value); //dGVOrders = DataGridView
  }

  private void SetBindingSRC(DataGridView dgv, BindingSource bs)
  {
    if (dgv.DataBindings.Equals(bs))
      return;

    if (!InvokeRequired)
    {
      dgv.DataSource = bs;
        return;
    }

    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
      dgv.DataSource = bs;
    }));
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
interface IMTMainForm
{
  BindingSource bSRCOrders { get; set; }
}
```

I have a presenter class:

```
class MTMainPresenter
{
  private readonly IMTMainForm _view;

  private void Subscribe(WebsocketClient wsc) 
  {
    client.Streams.OrderStream
      .Select(ordr => 
        Observable.FromAsync(async () => {
          HandleOrderResponse(ordr);
        }))
      .Concat() //All incoming orders are queued and that is the way I want it.
      .Subscribe();
  }

  private void HandleOrderResponse(OrderResponse response)
  {
    switch (response.Action)
    {
      case ExchAction.Insert:
        ??
        break;
      case ExchAction.Delete:
        ??
        break;
      case ExchAction.Update:
        ??
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

What I need are some suggestions for inserting, deleting and searching/updating data in the DataGridView so that my list always represents the status of my orders on the exchange.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I got it! :)

My form:

```
public partial class MTMainForm : Form, IMTMainForm
{
  public BindingSource bSRCOrders
  {
    get => (BindingSource)dGVOrders.DataSource;
    set => SetBindingSRC(dGVOrders, value); //dGVOrders = DataGridView
  }

  private void SetBindingSRC(DataGridView dgv, BindingSource bs)
  {
    //if (dgv.DataBindings.Equals(bs))   --> Commented this
    //  return;                          --> Commented this

    if (!InvokeRequired)
    {
      dgv.DataSource = bs;
      ((BindingSource)dgv.DataSource).ResetBindings(false); // Add this to refresh DGV
      return;
    }

    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
      dgv.DataSource = bs;
      ((BindingSource)dgv.DataSource).ResetBindings(false); // Add this to refresh DGV
    }));
  }
}
```

I also added a timer where I refresh the binding sources. I still have to check wether this is still necessary...

I created a new class with a List that I maintain. I also added a method to convert the list to a BindingSource that I use to replace the existing one...

```
class OrdersStatsHandler
{
    private readonly List<Order> _orderList = new List<Order>();

    public void HandleOrder(Order newOrder)
    {
        List<string> removeList = new List<string>() { newOrder.OrderId };

        switch (newOrder.OrdStatus)
        {
            case OrderStatus.Rejected:
            case OrderStatus.Filled:
            case OrderStatus.Canceled:
                _orderList.RemoveAll(r => removeList.Any(a => a == r.OrderId));
                break;
            case OrderStatus.New:
            case OrderStatus.PartiallyFilled:
                if (_orderList.Where(o => o.OrderId == newOrder.OrderId).Count() == 0)
                    _orderList.Add(newOrder);
                else
                {
                    _orderList.RemoveAll(r => removeList.Any(a => a == r.OrderId));
                    _orderList.Add(newOrder);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public BindingSource GetBindingSource()
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = _orderList;
        return bs;
    }
}
```

In my Presenter class I handle the response like this:

```
class MTMainPresenter
{
    private readonly IMTMainForm _view;
    private OrdersStatsHandler _orderStatsHandler;

    private void Subscribe(WebsocketClient wsc)
    {
        client.Streams.OrderStream
          .Select(ordr =>
            Observable.FromAsync(async () => {
                HandleOrderResponse(ordr);
            }))
          .Concat() //All incoming orders are queued and that is the way I want it.
          .Subscribe();
    }

    private void HandleOrderResponse(OrderResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Order o in response.Data)
            {
                _orderStatsHandler.HandleOrder(o);
            }

            var bs = _orderStatsHandler.GetBindingSource();
            _view.bSRCOrders = bs;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Log.Error(exc.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You're welcome! :)